# LTspice XVII solving Thevenin Resistance basics

Tags: resistance, ltspice, thevenin

Thevenin voltage is a snap, but how do I get R Thevenin?

[image: Thevenin Voltage]

Comment: One way is to supply a 1 A current source at OUT and solve. Do you see why? (For an example, see [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/435123/38098).) The other is to just do Thevenin analysis of your resistors as you go. For the circuit you provide (which is easier to solve for Rth than the link I gave), that's all you need.

Comment: OK and it shows me a chart with V and I want R.  Does ltspice solve for R?  I can do it by hand but want to use LTspice if I can.

Comment: Bingo!  Nice trick!  It gives me the exact number except in V instead of R.  V/1A=R.  Beautiful!  Thanks!!

Comment: I provided an answer that shows you a straight forward way to do this only considering the usual resistor divider idea, repeating it several times. Another way to go.

Answer (score 4):

Short your voltage source, add a 1A current source at the output and the voltage at the OUT net will represent the equivalent resistance.

Comment: Ahhh K so I have to solve for R myself using the V resultant and the 1A.  Suprised LTspice doesn't do it directly.

Comment: Got it!  Thanks!

Comment: It's also easy to calculate it yourself as well: short the voltage source and start calculating parallel equivalent, then series equivalent from left to right.

Comment: The 1A current source is a convenience. You can use other source (even a voltage source) and have LTSPice calculate voltage/current at the output node. You can easily add a formula at the graph.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take your schematic and break it down:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ficoEm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Follow the steps below:

1. Let's use the voltage source and \$R_1\$ and \$R_5\$, first. This first divider gives us \$V_{\text{TH}_1}=72\:\text{V}\cdot\frac{R_5}{R_1+R_5}\$ and \$R_{\text{TH}_1}=\frac{R_1\:R_5}{R_1+R_5}\$.
2. \$R_{\text{TH}_1}\$ is now in series with \$R_2\$. So \$V_{\text{TH}_2}=V_{\text{TH}_1}\cdot\frac{R_6}{R_{\text{TH}_1}+R_2+R_6}\$ and \$R_{\text{TH}_2}=\frac{\left(R_{\text{TH}_1}+R_2\right)\:R_6}{R_{\text{TH}_1}+R_2+R_6}\$.
3. \$R_{\text{TH}_2}\$ is now in series with \$R_3\$. So \$V_{\text{TH}_3}=V_{\text{TH}_2}\cdot\frac{R_7}{R_{\text{TH}_2}+R_3+R_7}\$ and \$R_{\text{TH}_3}=\frac{\left(R_{\text{TH}_2}+R_3\right)\:R_7}{R_{\text{TH}_2}+R_3+R_7}\$.
4. \$R_{\text{TH}_3}\$ is now in series with \$R_4\$. So the net Thevenin resistance is \$R_{\text{TH}_3}+R_4\$.

That's it. \$V_\text{TH}=V_{\text{TH}_3}\$ and \$R_\text{TH}=R_{\text{TH}_3}+R_4\$. Here I find \$V_\text{TH}=9\:\text{V}\$ and \$R_\text{TH}=1.5\:\text{k}\Omega\$.

You can also use nodal analysis as I earlier suggested and add a separate \$1\:\text{A}\$ current source as a second step. But for your circuit, it's not necessary. This one is too easy to solve by successive divider equivalents.